# How to get the context of an iframe (google payframe) using puppeteer

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

So basically I'm testing the adyen drop-in googlepay integration, for this I need to login, follow a link to the page with the gpay button, click it and then in the appearing popup I need to click the pay button.

I managed to accomplish the first steps and am lacking the last one which is to click the pay button.

Here's my toy script:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer-extra');
const StealthPlugin = require('puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth');

puppeteer.use(StealthPlugin());

const dotenv = require('dotenv');

dotenv.config();

const clickGooglePayButton = async () => {};

const loginFromPage = async (browser) => {
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto(process.env.LOGIN_LINK);

  const email = 'input[type="email"]';
  const password = 'input[type="password"]';

  await page.waitForSelector(email);
  await page.type(email, process.env.EMAIL);
  await page.keyboard.press('Enter');
  await page.waitForNavigation();

  await page.waitForSelector(password);
  await page.type(password, process.env.PASS);
  await page.keyboard.press('Enter');

  await page.waitForNavigation();

  return page;
}

const run = async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: false,
    slowMo: 50,
    args: [
      '--disable-web-security',
      '--disable-features=IsolateOrigins,site-per-process',
    ],
  });

  await loginFromPage(browser);
  const gpayTabRef = await browser.newPage();
  await gpayTabRef.goto(process.env.GPAY_LINK);

  const gpayButton = await gpayTabRef.waitForSelector('div.gpay-card-info-container-fill button');
  console.log(gpayButton);

  await gpayButton.click();
  const openPages = await browser.pages();
  console.log(openPages);

  const targets = browser.targets();

  const targetFrame = await browser.waitForTarget(target => target.url().includes('https://pay.google.com/gp/p/ui/payframe?origin'));
  console.log('returning the target type');
  console.log(targetFrame.type());
  console.log(await targetFrame.page());

}

run();
```

I tried playing around with targets, but looks like this pay frame is no page, cos the page method on this target simply resolves to `null`.

I've also tried playing around with frames:

```
  const frames = await gpayTabRef.frames();
  console.log('logging frames...');
  console.log(frames);
  const content = await frames[frames.length - 1].content();
```

but I'm not getting the content of that pay popup with the pay button...I feel that the solution is somewhere near but would very much appreciate some help.

Comment: Please, provide minimal reproducible example.

Comment: @Yaroslavm its already as reproducible as possible.

Comment: I just don't get what exactly you are asking for? For my credit card info or for a short lived link that can only be generated by the adyen integration?

Comment: Reproducible example, how to reach that source. I guess it is similar for many flows.

Comment: I mean something like: Open website.com -> Add product to card -> Click Pay -> Click Google Pay.

Without STR it's hard to say what happened in your environment.